# how to use nodejs async module?

Tags: node.js

This is a different question and I am unable to get a solution for this, please do not mark it duplicate.

I cannot access variable op outside the function. Should I be using a async module of nodjes?
I have two console.logs. But only inside function log works.

I have tried other questions answers. Still it is not working

```
var http = require('http');
console.log("hi")
var options = {
    host: 'api.usergrid.com',
    path: '/siddharth1/sandbox/restaurants'
};
var op = []; //declaring outside function
var req = http.get(options, function(res) {

    // Buffer the body entirely for processing as a whole.
    var bodyChunks = [];
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        // You can process streamed parts here...
        bodyChunks.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', function() {
        var body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);

        // ...and/or process the entire body here.
        var body2 = JSON.parse(body);

        op = body2.entities.map(function(item) {
            return item.name;
        });
        console.log(op); // only this works
    })
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + e.message);
});


console.log("outside function " + op); //this doesnt work


console.log('Server listening on port 80');
```

Comment: The console.log that doesn't work isn't working because it executes well before the callback returns from the server. The real question here is why do you need to look at the value outside of the callback? Let's answer that before talking about using async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js instantiates the variable op as an empty array:

```
var op = []; //declaring outside function
```

It then calls the .get() function of the http module, and passes it `options` and a callback function.

```
var req = http.get(options, function(res) {
  ...
});
```

The code inside the callback function is **not** executed until an HTTP GET request is received by your application.

Node then continues, and executes the remainder of your code:

```
console.log("outside function " + op); //this doesnt work
```

The above line is executed and indeed, op is an empty array as you defined it to be an empty array - and nothing has yet modified 'op'.

The server then idles, waiting for any incoming HTTP requests.

Much later, you of course issue a HTTP GET request to your server. The callback function you registered gets called, and the code inside that function executes.

If I were you I would look into some fundamental tutorials on Node.js, specifically looking into it's non-blocking model. Good luck.

Note: [Ryan Dahl's original node.js presentation](https://youtu.be/EeYvFl7li9E) is a rather long video and a little old, but perfectly explains the way Node.js works, and I highly recommend you give it a watch.

Comment: Thank you explaining in detail. I would definitely have a look. Unfortunately I have to show case my code tomorrow and I am struck with this :( Trying to find a monkey patch for now.